# javascript string replace sentence

Tags: javascript

I have this scenario on my chatbox where in I want to bypass the string from a built in application and replace it with specific phrase.

```
<div id="testdiv">
This is an example of a sentence that i want to replace.
</div>
```

I want to replace the following:

- "**This is an example of a**" with "**I replaced the**"
- "**that i want to replace**" with "**using javascript**"

The word "sentence" should remain and wont be affected.

So the **output** will be: `I replaced the sentence using javascript`

I used this code of mine, 2 function and it is working but I'm looking for someone's help to clean my code or other method like **split** or **concat** if applicable? And if possible to put it on 1 function with the same idea.

```
function replace1 () {
      var str1 = document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML;
      var ptrn1 = /This is an example of a/gi;
      var rep1 = "This is an example of a";
      var newstr1 = rep1.replace(ptrn1, "that i want to replace");
      document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML = newstr1;
  }

  function replace2 () {
      var str2 = document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML;
      var ptrn2 = /that i want to replace/gi;
      var rep2 = "that i want to replace";
      var newstr2 = rep1.replace(ptrn2, "using javascript");
      document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML = newstr2;
  }
```

Comment: I like it.. Is it an actual requirement

Comment: str1 and str2, rep1 and rep2 are not used?

Comment: Why do you use two functions?

Comment: @eol sorry, i used 2 functions because this is what i know to do it, thats why im looking for someones help here

Comment: @JinsPeter i think so :)

Comment: Think its time to pick an answer, @LearnSomethingNew

Comment: @Sventies yup, im trying all of them. thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function replace1 () {
  var str1 = document.getElementById("testdiv").innerText;
  var ptrn1 = /This is an example of a/gi;
  var ptrn2 = /that i want to replace/gi;
  var str2 = str1.replace(ptrn1, "I replaced the").replace(ptrn2, "using javascript");
  document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML = str2;
}
      
replace1()
```

```html
<div id="testdiv">
This is an example of a sentence that i want to replace.
</div>
```

Comment: output of this is "using javascript sentence using javascript"

Comment: sorry, i just copied your snippet, and there was a issue in the text you have provided, i ve corrected that, it should work fine

Comment: i was just thinking, what if the word "sentence" is changing every time and i want to replace it with static text for example "WORD". would it be possible too on my scenario?

Comment: i think it would be possible if you know the rest of your sentence. once you have processed your sentence, you can use a regex to filter out words and replace it with what you want..

Comment: thanks again for this one. i learn a lot from here and to all other who posted their answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get you right but why don't you simply write it in one function without the use of all these helper variables. I would suggest you something like this as an dynamic approach.

```
function replaceText(toReplace, target, string){
    toReplace.map((s, idx) => { string = string.replace(s.input, s.output) })  
    target.textContent = string
}

let toReplace = [
   { input: 'This is an example of a', output: 'I replaced the'},
   { input: 'that i want to replace', output: 'using JavaScript'}]

let elem = document.getElementById('testdiv')
let string = elem.textContent

replaceText(toReplace, elem, string)
```

https://jsbin.com/zaceveqiji/edit?html,js,output

Comment: it is also working and thank you so much for this. i appreciate it and i wish i can upvote all working answer provided to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a capturing group to capture the "sentence" content and wrap it with the desired replacements:

```
function replaceContents () {
      var str1 = document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML;
      var ptrn1 = /This is an example of a(.*)that i want to replace/gi;
      var replace1 = "I replaced the";
      var replace2 = "using javascript";
      var newstr1 = str1.replace(ptrn1, replace1+"$1"+replace2);
      document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML = newstr1;
  }
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7hw6o8sy/

Comment: it is also working and thank you so much for this. i appreciate it and i wish i can upvote all working answer provided to my question.

Comment: i was just thinking, what if the word "sentence" is changing every time and i want to replace it with static text for example "WORD". would it be possible too on my scenario?

Comment: Yes, this regex would find every arbitrary word between "This is an example of a" and "that i want to replace".

Comment: i don't know how to do it, the idea just came out to my mind. i think i'm gonna make another thread for this or is it okay to edit my post?

Answer (score 0):

you can use replace function like this `str.replace(...).replace(...)`

```js
function replacer() {
  var str1 = document.getElementById("testdiv");
  var newstr1 = str1.innerHTML.replace(/This is an example of a/gi, "I replaced the")
    .replace(/that i want to replace/gi, "using javascript");
  str1.innerHTML = newstr1;
}
replacer();
```

```html
<div id="testdiv">
  This is an example of a sentence that i want to replace.
</div>
```

Comment: it is also working and thank you so much for this. i appreciate it and i wish i can upvote all working answer provided to my question.

Comment: i was just thinking, what if the word "sentence" is changing every time and i want to replace it with static text for example "WORD". would it be possible too on my scenario?

Comment: use function with variables and pass it as `RegExp`

Comment: i don't know how to do it, the idea just came out to my mind. i think i'm gonna make another thread for this or is it okay to edit my post?

Answer (score 0):

You could use like this using split and join

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vzobx4u5/)

**Code**

```
function replace(){
 var notReplaced = "sentence";
 var part1 = "I replaced the ";
 var part2 = " using javascript";
 var mainString = document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML;
 var splitPieces = mainString.split(notReplaced);
 splitPieces[0] = part1;
 splitPieces[1] = part2;

 var result = splitPieces.join(notReplaced);
  console.log(result);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<body>
    <center>
    <h1> Sentence</h1><br>
    <div id="testdiv">
        This is an example of a sentence that i want to replace.
    </div><br>
    <input type='text' id='replace' placeholder="Replace"><br>
    <input type='text' id='with' placeholder="With"><br>
    <input type='submit' onClick="replaceSentence()">
    </center>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function replaceSentence(){
            var val = document.getElementById('testdiv').innerHTML; 
            document.getElementById('testdiv').innerHTML = val.replace(document.getElementById('replace').value,document.getElementById('with').value);
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

for any input:

```
  function replace() {
    var fixedPiece = "sentence";
    var firstPart = "I replaced the ";
    var secondPart = " using javascript";
    var wholeSentence = document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML;

    var index = wholeSentence.indexOf('sentence');
    var newSentence = wholeSentence.replace(wholeSentence.substr(0, index - 1), firstPart).substr(0, index + fixedPiece.length);

    var newSentence = newSentence.concat(secondPart);
    document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML = newSentence;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```js
function replace(totalString, keepString) {
  var newstr = totalString.split(keepString);
  var repstr1 = "I replaced the";
  var repstr2 = "using javascript";
  return [repstr1, repstr2].join(keepString);
}

var div = document.getElementById("testdiv");
div.innerHTML = replace(div.innerHTML, " sentence ");
```

```html
<div id="testdiv">
  This is an example of a sentence that i want to replace.
</div>
```

Comment: it is also working and thank you so much for this. i appreciate it and i wish i can upvote all working answer provided to my question.